# Trying to select all records where one column is the same and a different column is different in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I need to run a query in hive that will select all rows where column A occurs more than once with a different value in the last column

[image]

Comment: Is this what you're looking for `select * from x where a in (select a from x group by a having count(*) > 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(d) over (partition by a) as min_d,
             max(d) over (partition by a) as max_d
      from t
     ) t
where min_d <> max_d;
```